# Can't trace origin of corrupted preference file

Tags: macos, preferences, plist

I keep getting a corrupted preference file that auto-regenerates. I can't seem to pin it to any recent downloads and google has not been my friend.

org.stereovision.exploration.plist

Can't tell if it is having any knock-on effects but as it does not appear in any console logs I am assuming that it is having no ill effects.

Regards
Pat

Comment: Can you change the permissions on the file so it is read only - the the program writing to it should complain - Although I would expect only one program reads it and that is the one which also writes it

Comment: What i've done is delete all the info within the plist file via textwrangler. So far no evidence of any harm, but it is early yet.

Comment: Which directory are you finding the plist in?

Comment: /Volumes/user/Library/Preferences

Comment: Deleting info contained within file didn't work longterm so I have changed permissions on the file to write only, as mark suggested, and that seems to have done the trick. Still can't find source or associated app!

Comment: oops that didn't work either